# Eclipse start up error

Tags: eclipse

When I start my eclipse, it gives following error :

An internal error occurred during:

```
"Repository registry initialization".
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
```

Does anyone know how can I solve this error.??

Answer (score 0):

Once suggestion for this workspace is to rename
`.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi` to something else,
then try and startup.  This resets the basic perspectives and the views that
are open (and removes all open editors).

It won't reset the workspace. This should reset the plugin configuration, that is causing this issue. (The solution I am specifying is a generic solution to startup eclipse problems)

Comment: You are supposed to check in your Eclipse "WORKSPACE"(where your projects are located) folder and not eclipse installation folder.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Juno faced a similar problem it worked after that... my be your version is different..